# do-while loop multiple condition evaluation C++

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements, do-while

This semester having a C++ class. Previous semester we were learning Python and now doing one of the assignments i need to make a do-while loop that loops while a variable isnt equal one of multiple numbers in an array. 
In python i would use "not in" function, ex:

```
if a not in (1,2,3,4):
```

or something of that sort. 
My naive attempt do the same in C++ went like so:

```
do {...}while(userin != (1,2,3,4);
```

but obviously it doesnt work.

Does anyone know how to do this in C++?

Comment: Create an array with the elements that cant be in the user input. (use `std::array`). Then use `std::find`.

Comment: <del>You'll have to write a "helper function" where you check if the integer is in an array `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and return a boolean accordingly.</del> Probably wanna go with what @RickAstley wrote.

Comment: assuming you know the logic, the docs give a syntax solution http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do

Comment: i fixed this with using 'userin!=1||userin!=2||...' and so on, but its very tedious.  Yeah C++ aint gonna be as simple as Python :P

Comment: You kinda need to learn C++. And I mean, go through your course, or some book, or whatever. Asking about tiny pieces of basic syntax and data structures at SO won't be very productive... Like here, you are using a tuple. In C++ you might use a set.

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard library function **find** from the **algorithm** header. For example:

```
int user = // this comes from your code...;
std::vector<int> exclude{1,2,3,4};
do {...} while (std::find(exclude.begin(), exclude.end(), user) == exclude.end());
```

This will loop  while the user is not in the exclude array.

But you have to be careful what and how you are changing within your loop: user and/or exclude -> otherwise you can easily get an infinite loop. You have to ensure the termination condition, maybe with some additional counter etc.

You could also make your own templated function for searching value within some container, for example:

```
template<typename Container, typename T>
bool within(const Container& c, T value) {
    return std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), value) != std::end(c);
}
```

Then you could call it like:

```
do {...} while !within(exclude, user);
```

Other examples:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
std::cout << boolalpha 
    << within(v, 1) << std::endl
     << within(v, 5) << std::endl;

std::string s = "Hello world";
std::cout << within(s, 'o') << std::endl
          << within(s, 'x') << std::endl;
```

Here live example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/qEzDZ93HvCaU0bJb

Comment: Yeah thanks, i found out about this before i asked the question. I thought there was more elegant way of doing it, but thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: You can also make a helper function to makes thing a bit more legible, `bool within(int value, std::vector<int> const& values) { return std::find(values.begin(), values.end(), value) != values.end(); }` and then `do {...} while(!within(value, exclude));`.

Comment: @Eljay, yeah. I updated the answer but with a templated version, because it's more general.

Comment: @StPiere You should use `std::begin` and `std::end` for your template to work with arrays (e.g. `int [4]`). And you should pass `T` by reference, there is no point making a copy here.

Answer (score 1):

No other answer is pointing out the fact that there **is** a standard function for this in `<algorithm>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

    if (std::any_of(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int val){ return val == 3; })) // true
        std::cout << "3 is in a" << std::endl;

    if (std::any_of(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int val){ return val == 7; })) // false
        std::cout << "7 is in a" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Similarly there are [`std::all_of` and `std::none_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming array is sorted you can use [`bsearch`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/), othewise you need to implement search logic as was alrtold told.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in support for this in C++, so you have to implement it yourself. Here is one way.

```
int bar;
std::vector<int> arr{1, 2, 3, 4};
do {
   // Code
} while (std::find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), bar) == arr.end());
```

You could change `std::vector<int>` for `std::array<int, 4>`. The downside is that you have to specify the size, but it is faster than `vector`.

Comment: Prefer `std::array` over `std::vector` for statically sized containers.

Comment: @RickAstley While what you are saying is correct, I think this is better for anyone so fresh at C++ that he actually asks this question.

Comment: @klutt When someone is learning a new language, you should actually try to show him best practices. With `-O3`, the code with `std::array` is the same as testing `bar` against 1 / 2 / 3 / 4, with vector there are no optimization.

Comment: @Holt I fixed a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Even though `std::find` inside a temporary `std::vector` *might* get optimized away by the compiler (it most certainly won't<sup>1</sup>), a guaranteed *efficient* way would be to just compare "by hand":

```
do {...} while (userin != 1 && userin != 2 && userin != 3 && userin != 4);
```

In your specific example, if `userin` is an integer type, you could just:

```
do {...} while (userin < 1 || userin > 4);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Compare [this](https://godbolt.org/g/dD4Zif) (vector), [this](https://godbolt.org/g/kw6EEz) (array) and [that](https://godbolt.org/g/tF9738).